# Render Higher Resolution but keep same aspect ratio without it being cropped?

Tags: rendering, camera, resolution

I'm trying to render an image 1080x1350 but 2x so 2160x2700 for a higher resolution, everytime I render it crops like most of the image and just renders only the left bottom corner even though in the viewport the camera aspect ratio is still correct to I how I want it to be 4:5? any solution to this?[image]

Comment: Provided screen is just a part of render ... A tile of unfinished rendering ... Probably wait until render is done.